# Ubuntu посылает нежелательные dns запросы

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, dns, настройки

Когда я включаю ubuntu, запускаю wireshark, подключаю ubuntu к сети, вижу, что от моего ip посылается dns запросы на сайты типа "ubuntu.com". Как это можно выключить, в каких настройках копаться?

Comment: Ну, можно предположить, что система проверяет доступные обновления в репозитории, расположенном на *ubuntu.com.

Comment: Ещё может запрашивать новости для `motd`.

Comment: ещё проверка доступности интернета